# How to know directory where an executable was launched from in OS/X?

Tags: c, macos, directory, program-entry-point, finder

When a C program written in the conventional `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` style is launched from the Finder, it starts in the home directory of the user who launched it.  (e.g. */Users/Fork*).

Is there any fancy hook by which such a terminal-based program can know what directory it was launched in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain the full path for the program's binary image via [`_NSGetExecutablePath`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dyld.3.html). Canonicalise that using e.g. [`realpath`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/realpath.3.html) and then strip off the filename using e.g. [`dirname`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dirname.3.html) and you have the directory the program was started from.